# Which seffer is the תשובת ב׳י in Pischei Tshuvah Yoreh De'ah 112?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot

The Shulchan Aruch in Yoreh De'ah 112 sif 16 brings an opinion regarding a traveler who is stringent not to eat bread of a non-Jew should wait four mil to reach the Jewish baked bread.

Pischei Tshuva #6 first brings a Chochmas Adam stating that this opinion would require one to go one mil out of their way, just like prayers. But then he quotes a seffer he abbreviates as תשובת ב׳י
who says there is no difference if one is riding on a horse or walking or whether the road is is bad, rather the only consideration is if he is traveling alone or with his children and household members.

Which seffer is תשובת ב׳י?

Comment: For the record, I looked at the options in HebrewBooks for sefarim that start with בית י, but nothing seemed to fit the bill.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is **ספר בית יעקב** - a sefer of responsa published in the year 5456 in דירנפורט by **רב יעקב בן שמואל אב"ד צויזמיר** *(now צויזמיר is known as Sandomierz, Poland)*.

See **שאלה לה** starting at the bottom left of [this on HebrewBooks](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=628&pgnum=52) and extending for another two pages.

See a nice bio (in Hebrew) on the author [in the intro to a recent reprint of his sefer](https://alehzayis.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%91.pdf). Also see [this](https://www.kedem-auctions.com/he/node/122246) for a little more on the author.